# Как получить знак за метку?

Tags: поддержка, метки, знаки

Заходя на страницы гуру Stackoverflow (людей с рейтингом несколько десятков тысяч), вижу у них знаки, присуждённые за ответы на вопросы с определённой меткой. Например, бронзовый знак Java:

> Заработать не менее 100 баллов рейтинга за минимум 20 ответов, не
>   отмеченных как общие, на вопросы с меткой `java`

Для бронзового знака требования не так уж и высоки, однако у меня, например, нет ни одного знака, хотя, на мой взгляд, сходные требования, например для Python, я выполнил – 39 сообщений и рейтинг за них явно более 100.

Более того, в списке доступных знаков в моём профиле нет ни одного знака за метки, вследствие чего я не в состоянии отслеживать прогресс.

Итак, вопрос: почему всё так? Есть ли какие-то дополнительные требования для получения вышеописанных знаков? Если да, то какие?

Comment: В профиле, вместо следующей привилегии, можно отслеживать метку. Думаю, так прогресс будет нагляднее.

Comment: Рейтинг за метки даётся только за ответы, а не за вопросы. Поэтому у вас пока не хватает. Чаще отвечайте -- появятся и знаки за метки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Общий рейтинг по метке [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) у вас 33:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P.S.** минусы тоже учитываются.

**P.P.S.** предполагаю, что произошла путаница с голосами за ответы и количеством репутации за плюс. После плюса вам дают `10` репутации, но этот плюс считается как `1` очко для этого знака.

Comment: Разве слово "общий" не означает суммарный рейтинг по всем вопросам? Если нет, то объясните, пожалуйста, что такое общий рейтинг.

Comment: До меня только что дошло. Большое спасибо.